# Questions on CA authorization (balance-transfer hyperledger)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ca

I am trying to run the balance-transfer example in the link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/balance-transfer#sample-rest-apis-request

I want to ask that why I can still invoke the chaincode and run successfully when the authorization: Bearer is org1 but the invoke is done on Org2(["peer1.org2.example.com")? Why this will not cause authorization error?

In addition, why can I query the chaincode use Org1 certificate on Org2. Are there any setup issues related to the CA?

```
echo "POST invoke chaincode on peers of Org1"
echo
TRX_ID=$(curl -s -X POST \
http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/mycc \
-H "authorization: Bearer $ORG1_TOKEN" \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
"peers": ["peer1.org2.example.com"],
"fcn":"move",
"args":["a","b","10"]
}')
echo "Transacton ID is $TRX_ID"
echo
echo
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the peers in JSON string refers to the endorsing peer. It can be left empty. The authorization is based on the token and the transaction will be completed on org1 peers based on the log.